# How to specify a templated type as template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, embedded

I am writing an microcontroller application. I really would like something like this:

```
template<uint8_t pin_number, uint32_t port_address, uint32_t irq_address>
struct PinDescription {
    constexpr uint8_t number = pin_number;
    constexpr uint32_t port  = port_address;
    constexpr uint32_t irq   = irq_address;
}
```

To do something like this:

```
template<PinDescription pin, class mode>
class DigitalPin {
DigitalPin() = default;
    static void begin()
    {
        mode::begin(pin::number, pin::port, pin::irq);
    }
}
```

The "mode" is a struct with static methods.

I have searched in stackoverflow, but the best I discovered was template template parameters, which is not exactly what I  want. I believe I could use the general typename or class. But the reason I want to specify the type is to take advantage of auto complete.

Do you have any idea of how to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: Just use `class`. Autocomplete feature is quite limited when it comes to templates. Note that specializations of `PinDescription` might have no data members at all. How would autocomplete know that?

Comment: There is no `PinDescription` class, only `PinDescription<pin_number, port_address, irq_address>`, which requires template template parameters. But you can define a `DigitalPin<pin_number, port_address, irq_address, mode>` and add a deduction guideline for `DigitalPin<PinDescription<pin_number, port_address, irq_address>, class mode> -> DigitalPin<pin_number, port_address, irq_address, class mode>` and then I think you have what you want.

Comment: Or pass the PinDescription as argument to the constructor. You made it a class so you can pass a dummy instance of it and use that to deduce the template parameters.